# Changing The Colour Of A Contour Plot

Tags: plotting, color

I have produced used the following code to create a contour plot:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

However, I would like to modify this plot so that when the function is **positive** the shading is **blue**, and when it is **negative** the shading is **red**.

Now I know there's already similar threads on this site to achieving this but I would like to impose another condition which makes things trickier.

I would also like the contours lines to have the OPPOSITE colour to the shading (i.e if the region is shaded blue then I want the contours to be red). The contours can be isolated by turning shading off:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ContourShading -> None]
```

So I would like the contours to be coloured as follows:

[image: The Contours]

Combined with the shading, I hope that the final image will look like this:

**The Goal**

[image: Final Result]

I would be really grateful if someone could shed some light on this.

I'm really hoping there's a way of implimenting an IF statement which will condition on the sign of the function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [(6916)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6916/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A non-hackish method using [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html):

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ContourShading -> {Red, Blue}, Contours -> {{0}},
 Mesh -> 4, MeshFunctions -> {Max[Cos[#] + Cos[#2], 0] &, Min[Cos[#] + Cos[#2], 0] &}, 
 BaseStyle -> Thick, MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue},
 PlotPoints -> 100
]
```

[image]

---

Here is a way using only contours but requiring manually generated styles.  I was hoping that a function could be given directly to `Contours` for automatic generation but at least as I formulated it this did not work.

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  ContourShading -> {Red, Red, Red, Red, Red, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue}, 
  Contours -> Array[If[# > 0, {#, Red}, {#, Blue}] &, 9, {-2, 2}]
]
```

Alternatively:

```
sty = If[# > 0, {#, Blue}, {#, Red}] & /@ Range[-2, 2, 1/2]

ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
 ContourShading -> (sty[[All, 2]] /. {Red -> Blue, Blue -> Red}), Contours -> sty]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! (IOU one upvote.)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks!  I don't know if this is best however.  I often wonder how [Heike](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/46/heike) would do it were she here.

Comment: This Alternative solution is really nice as it uses terminology of which I am familiar with. However, could I ask why you've included 'Red', and 'Blue' five times each in the list?

Comment: @MrS100 Because unlike the first method I could not separate the number contour lines from the number of contour fill styles.  With only `ContourShading -> {Red, Blue}` here I would get a striped plot instead.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I've just tested this now and I see exactly what you mean. I'm struggling to understand what the function  `& /@ Range[#, #2, 1/2] &[-2, 2]'` is doing as changing the values dramatically changes the result. I ask this because I have not seen this function before used in this context and I am keen to understand your choice of parameters.

Comment: @MrS100 Sorry, I forget what can be confusing sometimes.  That's two nested anonymous functions. Further I only wrote it that way because I had hoped I could give the `Contours` option as a function, but it didn't work.  Instead I should replace it with `If[# > 0, {#, Red}, {#, Blue}] & /@ Range[-2, 2, 1/2]`.  Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! The above simplification produces the required result. I'll just have to read up exactly what the numbers -2,2,1/2 are actually doing. This has been my favourite answer and uses material which I am relatively comfortable with and I'll now mark it as such.

Comment: @MrS100 Oh, `-2` through `2` is simply the range of values over which I wanted to produce contours, and `1/2` is the interval.  I also used `Array` in the first case of the second section, which may have a syntax that is easier to use since I can directly specify `9` contours therein.

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the clarification. You've been much help.

Comment: Is `Subdivide[]` available in your version? You could use that instead of `Range[]`.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm much more comfortable with that command. I shall try it now. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

This rather hackish solution relies on the fact that the `Tooltip[]` objects within the output of `ContourPlot[]` store the height of the corresponding (set of) contours:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 π}, {y, 0, 4 π}, 
            ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Blue}, LogisticSigmoid[2 #]] &), 
            ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> 20] /.
Tooltip[stuff_, c_] :> Tooltip[Prepend[Cases[stuff, _Line],
                                       Directive[{Blue, Red}[[UnitStep[c] + 1]],
                                       Opacity[0.5], CapForm["Butt"]]], c]
```

[image: looks a bit trippy to me]

Comment: Thanks for the response J. M! I've upvoted as the code works as required.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another hackish solution that however regenerates the contour plot multiple times is the following combination:

```
Show[
 (* Generate the shaded areas *)
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> Function[z, If[z >= 0, Blue, Red]],
  ContourStyle -> None
  ],

 (* Generate the contours *)
 MapThread[
  ContourPlot[
    Boole[#1[Cos[x] + Cos[y], 0]] (Cos[x] + Cos[y]),
    {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, Contours -> 4,
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, #2], ContourShading -> None
    ] &,
  {{Greater, Less}, {Red, Blue}}
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[Mr. Wizard's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107956/27951) presented in his answer above is clearly superior, but I put this together before I saw his answer, so I thought I might as well post it anyway.

Comment: I like this response as this is how I initially thought about approaching the problem - by essentially combining two results. Upvoted

Answer (score 2):

I would also define my color style and use it like this:

```
   Clear[contours]
contours[n_?OddQ, color1_, color2_] := Module[{m},
  m = IntegerPart[n/2];
  cont = n; 
  col = Join[ConstantArray[color1, m], {Gray}, 
    ConstantArray[color2, m]];];

contours[11, Blue, Red]

p1 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> col, Contours -> cont];
p2 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> (If[# <= 0, Red, Blue] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> 1];
Show[p2, p1]
```

[image]

not ot get something close to your Goal picuter you can sue Show

Comment: I somehow didn't see this answer before adding the second method to mine; sorry if I plagiarized accidentally, and +1.

Comment: Upvoted. This is a clever solution to the problem. I've only just become familiar with the show function today, but it been of use already.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  not at all and thanks for Upvote :-)