# Replicating $\LaTeX$'s pgfplot Style in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, color, latex

I'm trying to replicate the plot theme of $\LaTeX$'s pgtplots for 3D surfaces in Mathematica's Plot3D Function. The goal is to create something similar to this:

[image]

So I played around with the opacity and different color gradients for a bit until i got this:

```
 Plot3D[Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#3 + .1, ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}][#3]] &),
 Mesh -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

However, I want the ColorFunction directives to be applied to the mesh rather than the surface. My approach was to simply do something like this:

```
 Plot3D[Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False,
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0],
 MeshStyle -> ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#3 + .1, ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}][#3]] &),
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

But apparently, this idea is completely wrong. It seems to me that MeshStyle will not accept values that depend on the plotted function. Is there any way to make this work within the Plot3D function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there is. Read [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6916/can-the-color-in-meshstyle-be-specified-by-a-colorfunction-such-as-sunsetcolor). ``With[{plot=Plot3D[Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]}, With[{cf = ColorData["RedBlueTones"][#3] &}, plot /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, g_, opts___] :> GraphicsComplex[pts, g /. Line[p_] :> Line[p, VertexColors -> MapThread[cf, Part[Rescale /@ Transpose[pts], All, p]]], opts]]]``

Comment: @Domen - your version that keeps the `GraphicsComplex` intact is much more responsive.  I will borrow from it if you don't mind.

Comment: @JasonB., not mine, of course, just changed the function in [Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109249/75628) :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I noticed that for plots like this you get a significantly better performance when rotating the `Graphics3D` if you keep the answer inside a `GraphicsComplex` and avoid calling `Normal`.  Borrowing from [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261005/replicating-latexs-pgfplot-style-in-mathematica/261007#comment649668_261005) and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109249/75628), and wrapping it in a function you get

```
ClearAll @ MeshPlot3D;
Options[MeshPlot3D] = Options @ Plot3D;
SetOptions[MeshPlot3D,
    {
        ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}][#3]&),
        Mesh -> Full, PlotPoints -> 50,PlotStyle->None
    }
];
MeshPlot3D[args__, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{plot},
    plot = With[
        {options = FilterRules[{opts}, Except[ColorFunction | ColorFunctionScaling]]},
        Plot3D[args,
            options, Mesh -> OptionValue[Mesh],PlotStyle -> OptionValue[PlotStyle],
            PlotPoints -> OptionValue[PlotPoints]
        ]
    ];
    ReplaceAll[plot,
        gc_GraphicsComplex :> addColorFunction[
            gc, OptionValue[ColorFunction], OptionValue @ ColorFunctionScaling
        ]
    ]
];
Attributes[MeshPlot3D] = {HoldAll}

addColorFunction[GraphicsComplex[pts_, g_, opts___], cf_, scaling_] := With[
    {rescale = If[TrueQ[scaling], Rescale, Identity]},
    GraphicsComplex[pts,
        ReplaceAll[g,
            Line[p_] :> Line[p,
                VertexColors -> MapThread[cf, Part[Map[rescale, Transpose[pts]], All, p]]
            ]
        ],
        opts
    ]
]
```

Called via

```
MeshPlot3D[Sin[Sqrt[(x ^ 2) + y ^ 2]] / Sqrt[(x ^ 2) + y ^ 2],
    {x, -2 * Pi, 2 * Pi},
    {y, -2 * Pi, 2 * Pi},
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100,
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
]
```

[image]

or

```
MeshPlot3D[x / Exp[(x ^ 2) + y ^ 2],
    {x, -2, 2},
    {y, -2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[0.65 * (1 + -z)]],
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Blue]
]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) The OP's figure seems to be using the so-called "cool" colormap from MATLAB, so to emulate that, one can use `ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#3, 1 - #3, 1] &)`.

Comment: Great job. Thanks. How to export it as a high-quality .eps figure? `Export["highquality.eps", %]`  doesn't give high-quality figure? (Mathematica 13 on Windows 11)

Answer (score 9):

We can use the simple trick from  [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261019/125): Define

```
f = ReplaceAll[Rule[VertexColors, None] -> Rule[VertexColors, Automatic]];
```

and simply add the option `DisplayFunction -> f` to `Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[Sin[Sqrt[(x^2) + y^2]]/Sqrt[(x^2) + y^2], {x, -2*Pi, 
      2*Pi}, {y, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  Mesh -> 50, 
  DisplayFunction -> f,
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[],
  ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#3, 1 - #3, 1] &),
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

where I used the color function suggested by J.M. in comments. If we use the color function in OP

```
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#3 + .1, ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}][#3]] &)
```

we get

[image]

A function that applies `ColorFunction` to mesh lines and `PlotStyle` to polygon faces:

```
ClearAll[meshPlot3D]

SetAttributes[meshPlot3D, HoldAll];

meshPlot3D[args__, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot3D]] := Module[
  {df = ReplaceAll[Rule[VertexColors, None] -> Rule[VertexColors, Automatic]]}, 
  Show[Plot3D[args, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> None, opts],
   Plot3D[args, DisplayFunction -> df, PlotStyle -> FaceForm[], opts]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
meshPlot3D[Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> 50,
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[],
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#3 + .1, RGBColor[#3, 1 - #3, 1]] &),
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

> ```
> same picture as above
> ```

Using the second example from Jason B.'s answer:

```
meshPlot3D[x/Exp[(x^2) + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Mesh -> 50, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[{Opacity[.5], Blue}], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[0.65*(1 + -z)]], 
 ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Great job. Thanks. How to export it as a high-quality .eps figure? `Export["highquality.eps", %]`  doesn't give high-quality figure? (Mathematica 13 on Windows 11)